# 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command in terminal

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, migrate, laravel-artisan

I installed php5 on monday and it was working with no problems and it's been working up until today when I tried to do a "php artisan migrate" command in the terminal and it said it wasn't recognized, I have the php5 folder saved in "C:\" and hasn't been moved since installation.[image]

[image]

Comment: `php`, or `php5`...?!

Comment: path variable updated?

Comment: Check the environment variable path. Check if you need to run the php-win.exe or php.exe

Comment: Use ready to go package like `wamp`, `xampp` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Probably You should append directory path of your php.exe to windows PATH environment variable. But be careful by changing this variables. Some information can be found here: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html or just use Google for more examples.

Comment: Changing the PHP environment variable to the appropriate doesn't imply a high risk....

Comment: I'm sure I already done that any chance it could have changed itself or maybe I've just accidentally moved something I'll try it the now

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try `php -v` from the command prompt. If you get something like **PHP 5.6.10** as output, then your php exists in your path.

In case your PATH is not set, you can use the `SET` command to set your PHP for that particular instance. Or you can go to My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables and append your php directory to the PATH variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled wamp and in doing so moved my old wamp folder to the desktop forgetting that I had used the wamp php file as my environment path. Ty for all your suggestions